# configure nginx to read the css file kept in amazon bucket into browser

Tags: css, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I have an amazon s3 bucket which contains css files.
Now I want to read them onto browser.

The request is made as www.example.com/folder1/css/style.css

The location in nginx configuration file is set as

```
location ~* ^/folder1/css/(.*) {
    proxy_pass https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/css/$1 ;
}
```

But the browser gives error 404.

I ensured that regex is being matched as when I put some website through proxy_pass, the website is displayed.

How do I read css files in amazon bucket?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was already a rule before which was getting matched before this rule.

I managed to read css file using rewrite.

```
location ~* \.css {
    rewrite ^/folder1/css/(.*) https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/css/$1 last;
}
```

I also found that nginx couldn't restart when used proxy_pass in location mentioned above.